# ERC20 Token on wrong Online Wallet

Tags: erc-20

I joined an ICO for the first time and transferred an ERC20 Token to an Online- Wallet which doesn't support this. The wallet name is Ether.li. Now I want to transfer Tokens back to Myetherewallet and I don't know how to do it?

Is there a way to transfer my ERC20 Token back to Myetherwallet?

Thanks.

Comment: Having the private key of your wallet you may use myetherwallet to invoke token contract and transfer back your tokens

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Big Problem- ERC20 Token on wrong Wallet](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/18582/big-problem-erc20-token-on-wrong-wallet)